# issue getting elements from XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I'm trying to retrieve some data from my XML file and I want to insert it inside an unordered list. This is how my Ajax code looks like:

```
var request;
//For backward compatibility
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.open('GET','data.xml');
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // if((request.readyState === 4) && (request.Status===200)){
        console.log(request.responseXML);
        var items = request.responseXML.getElementByTagName('name');
        alert('hello');
        var ouptput = '<ul>';
        for (var i = 0; i >= items.length; i++) {
            output += '<li>' + items[i].firstChild.nodeValue + '</li>';
        }
        output += '</ul>';
        document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output;
    //} 
}
request.send();
```

This code doesn't read my XML file, it gives me an error saying `'Response XML is null(Type error)'` I tried to use this in a server(localhost) but it didn't work either.

Can someone please give me an idea how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us your Xml?

Comment: Why is `if((request.readyState === 4) && (request.Status===200)){` commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used jQuery to solve this... this is how i did this.....

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".update").append("<ul></ul>");
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('book').each(function(){
          var sTitle = $(this).find('title').text();
          var sprice = $(this).find('price').text();
          $("<li></li>").html(sTitle + ", " + sprice).appendTo(".update ul");
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
      }
      });
    });

</script>
```